Flutter CupertinoPageScaffold Remove the Space on the Top of the Screen
What I am trying to achieve is to remove the space on top of the screen in CupertinoPageScaffold. I know that the purpose is to place the content to a safe place but I am trying to create a page coming from bottom and I need to remove all the padding and margin in CupertinoPageScaffold.
Do you know how can I achieve it?
This is what I have right now.

